# Tricky queue use between two CPUs

Tags: c, queue, embedded, message-queue

**cliff notes version**
The TI F28377S has two CPUs, a main and a secondary CPU (CLA, which can only perform one task at a time, with uninterrupted tasks) -they share message areas of RAM. When quickly feeding a queue about 15 bytes (of a max 32 queue length) that the CLA will send out, sometimes a few bytes will never be transmitted. I think there is some issue with the CPU interrupts that is causing single bytes to occasionally get "lost" while handing them over to the buffer.

**full version**
(This is using the TI F28377S which has a main CPU clocked at 200 MHz, and a secondary independent CLA that runs at the same speed, but can only execute one task at a time. They can share one-way writeable variables).

I'm a little stumped on how to do this more complex task, involving the CLA and a queue.

Some quick background: I have two main CLA tasks, the first (Task1) is triggered by the ADC end of conversion (which itself is triggered by Timer0 at 100 kHz), and the second (Task2) is triggered by Timer0 itself (this was arrived at after much experimenting, and tweaking, as whenever I had Task2 running more often than the ADC task, the ADC task would never start - so I set them both up to use the same interval, only staggered). Task1 works perfectly, storing the ADC results in a simplistic ring buffer, and performing a simple calculation in the Task1 after-completion ISR. The second mostly works.

Task2 is used to toggle some GPIO pins for communicating with an external device. Because the total length of the codes are on the order of 100's of microseconds, instead of delaying, I use a simple case structure on each trigger to determine if it should: do nothing, turn on the code pins, turn on the strobe pin, turn off the strobe pin, turn off the code pins. This way each time the task is called, it completes nearly instantaneously, with the output codes being the proper length for the external device. The task works on one code per time, and once it is done, attempts to grab another from a queue. If none, it just continues passing right through.

Now, the tricky part. I have two requirements: 1) that I can add bytes to the end of the queue faster than the task will consume them (pretty easy in theory and practice) and 2) that I can add a byte to the front of the queue (not replacing the currently transmitting byte, just the front of the queue). The first ability is to send medium-short messages (2-20 characters). This second ability is necessary to send a single byte about any external interrupts that come in - as quickly as possible, and even in the middle of transmitting a message. I've set it up so that the Task sends exactly 1 byte per 500 microseconds (~300 "on" and ~200 "off). This way, if an interrupt message comes in, it will be guaranteed to be received less than 1 ms after occurring.

What is currently work is this: a function on the CPU that takes incoming bytes (one at a time) and adds them to a CPU2CLA buffer and increments a CPU2CLA length counter. Each time Task2 is run, it checks this queue and grabs one byte from the front of a CLAonly buffer, increases its own buffer length, and flags that a byte was consumed. When the Task2 after-task ISR is run, it will check if a byte was consumed, and remove the first-most byte from the CPU2CLA buffer. Currently this double buffer system doesn't have a flag for adding to front, so it doesn't take care of the interrupt case.

What I tried previously was to have a Task3 which took one byte that was passed CPU2CLA and run it from the CPU with a Task3andWait. Although this method should in theory take care of both requirements, about half of the time a byte or two of a message would never get transmitted (a single byte always got sent).

A CLA task can never be interrupted, but a CPU task can. This is why I tried to have all modifications of the queue occur only in the CLA, so that way there was never an indeterminate state that could interrupt a queue modification.

Comment: TL:DR. If you "can add bytes to the end of the queue faster than the task will consume them" you will need to block the input. If that is the basic problem which requires you to post bytes to the front of the queue, then you must surely be making a **value judgement** on incoming bytes: ergo your functions are doing more processing than they should, hence the bottleneck.

Comment: The queue is only 32 bytes long right now (fixed). And my incoming function does a simple check if length == max_length, exit (i.e. drop the byte).

Comment: Then on what premise do you post bytes to the front of the queue? How necessary is the data? Can you afford to lose it? If so, just reset the buffer, when you cannot procees the incoming data quickly enough.

Comment: Same function (with a boolean flag for front/back). If full, ignore. If not, then shift all bytes back 1 place, and place new byte at the front. I should add that the test cases have never been more than 15 bytes so far, and always appended to the end.

Comment: That is giving even more workload.

Comment: Huh? Never more than 15 bytes in a 32-bit buffer? Then what is the problem?

Comment: I'm confused by your response. If I add a byte to the front of the queue, it has to shift everything back. The problem is most likely some mix of the interrupts that occur upon task completion on the main CPU, and when the CPU is trying to send bytes to the CLA.

Comment: Please define your problem, in less than 100 words, with example [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: I cannot put the bare-minimum explanation -and- necessary code in 100 words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like splitting the high-priority and normal priority items into separate buffers would be a near-optimal solution here.

It would also ensure that if a high-priority item, a normal-priority item, and another high-priority item are produced before anything is consumed, the high-priority items will be consumed before the normal-priority items.

(Using a single buffer, that case leads to the normal-priority item being consumed before the second high-priority item. I suspect that is highly undesirable.)

If there is an item in the high-priority buffer, that will be consumed next. Otherwise, an item in the normal-priority buffer will be consumed.

Both buffers have a single producer and a single consumer (thus, *SPSC* type), and are handled in a simple first-in-first-out manner; therefore, a lockless circular buffer implementation (for each buffer) should work just fine here.

(If only 32 bytes are available for the two buffers, consider trying a 8:24 split first.)

Comment: I like this. I didn't think about two queues, but that completely solves the issue of an item being inserted at the beginning. I'll try it out.

Comment: I will add, that I'll have to figure out how to get a normal circular buffer working between two memory "domains". (The CPU and CLA have either RW or R access to any individual variable, but that is defined before compiling. So it isn't possible for both the producer and consumer to both be able to change the length).

Comment: @AdamJones: If `next` is the index of the next byte to be consumed, and `last` is the index of the last byte to be consumed (both modulo buffer length), then only the producer writes to `next`, and consumer to `last`.

Comment: That's the problem. the consumer (CLA, in this case) can never write to a variable owned by the CPU. And although the CLA code can be written in C, it can't use libraries that were complied for the CPU - so I can't use the ring buffer library I'm currently using - I'll have to extract a few functions and rewrite them.